# Python, Why doesn't the returned win32api.ShellExecute handle work for win32gui.GetWindowRect

Tags: python, winapi

OK, so in the following code

```
import win32api
import win32gui
hwnd = win32api.ShellExecute(None, "open", "notepad.exe", "test.txt", None, 6)
rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
```

I open Notepad successfully and receive a return value >32 as to indicate the success of the execution. In the docs: http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32api__ShellExecute_meth.html
The return value is specified as an instance handle, so I expected to be able to use this handle as the paramenter for the GetWindowRect call. Docs: http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__GetWindowRect_meth.html

In my debugger I can see that hwnd equal an {long}42, and my GetWindowRect call returns a error 1400, Invalid window handle.

So why is the handle wrong, and how can I get a usable handle?

Comment: Even if you got back a valid handle, an instance handle is not the same as a window handle.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the return value is of type HINSTANCE but it is not a true instance and can only be used to compared against various error codes. Historically in 16 bit windows an instance handle was used to identify a particular executable or DLL instance but even then that was not the same as a window handle.

> **Return value**
>
> Type: HINSTANCE
>
> If the function succeeds, it returns a value greater
>   than 32. If the function fails, it returns an error value that
>   indicates the cause of the failure. The return value is cast as an
>   HINSTANCE for backward compatibility with 16-bit Windows applications.
>   It is not a true HINSTANCE, however. It can be cast only to an int and
>   compared to either 32 or the following error codes below.

So far as I know, the best way to get a usable window handle is to iterate over the top level windows in the system until you find one with the expected class and title.

Here's a code extract based on something I wrote years ago that looks for windows with matching title and class:

```
from win32gui import EnumWindows, GetClassName
from win32ui import CreateWindowFromHandle

def toplevelWindows(s, klass):
    res = []
    def callback(hwnd, arg):
        name = GetClassName(hwnd)
        w = CreateWindowFromHandle(hwnd)
        title = w.GetWindowText()
        if s in title or name==klass:
            res.append(w)
    EnumWindows(callback, 0)
    return res
```

Comment: You should state that `HINSTANCE` and `HWND` are **unrelated**, anyway.

Comment: thanks for the solid answer.. 
I had found related information, but never clearly stating that they are not related handles.
Part of me just couldn't believe that no reference remained that could be used, and that a lookup would be required.

Comment: Another very useful link with a solution from the extension author:
[link](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/find-the-window-for-my-subprocess.html)